# Java Wiremock - mock external server during testing

Tags: java, wiremock

Suppose the application is dependent on a REST service on a **external server**, http://otherserver.com. For testing, I would like to simulate the external rest call (via Wiremock) within a JUnit environment. Starting a seperate server consumes time and is not easy. Working with WiremockRule looks the right direction. Creating simulation controllers is not an elegant way as Wiremock is available.

E.g. get( "http://otherserver.com/service3/");

PS: of course I know that I can simulate a REST call via Mockito.

Simulating localhost with Wiremock is easy. How can I use that code to simulate **other servers** and services? I copied parts from the popular Baeldung examples.

```
public class WireMockDemo {
    @Rule
    public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule();


    @Test
    public void wireMockTestJunitOtherServer() {
        try {
            // **this does not work...** 
            configureFor("otherserver.com", 8080);

            stubFor(get(urlPathMatching("/service2/.*"))
                    .willReturn(aResponse()
                            .withStatus(200)
                            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                            .withBody("\"testing-library\": \"WireMock\"")));

            // Test via simple client
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://otherserver:8080/service2/test");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            String stringResponse = convertHttpResponseToString(httpResponse);
            System.out.println( "Response = " + stringResponse);

            // Test via JUnit
            verify(getRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/service2/wiremock")));
            assertEquals(200, httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            assertEquals("application/json", httpResponse.getFirstHeader("Content-Type").getValue());
            assertEquals("\"testing-library\": \"WireMock\"", stringResponse);
        } catch( Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Support methods
    private String convertHttpResponseToString(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
        return convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
    }
    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        String string = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        scanner.close();
        return string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your application code should not have the `http://otherserver.com` hardcoded, it should be configurable. When running normally it should point to `http://otherserver.com`, when running in test mode it should be pointed to `http://localhost:<port>` where `<port>` is where you have started your Wiremock server (preferably dynamic to avoid port clashes)

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR:

No, you cannot.

What WireMock does, is to establish a Jetty server simulating a remote server you need to send request to. However, it does not change your `hosts` file or DNS mapping and automatically "redirect" your real request for remote server to localhost. In tests you still need to send request to `localhost`.

What you can do, if you are using Spring Boot, is to create two `application.yml` file(or another properties file) in `main` and `test` package, with same structure of keys, but the value in `src/main/resources/application.yml` is the real URL you request(like `http://example.com/api`), and that in `src/test/resources/application.yml` you put `localhost/api`.

---

By the way, to clarify, `MockMvc` is not for simulation of *external 3rd party server request that your application depends on*, but **requests sent to the endpoints of your application**. In MockMvc tests, your application is who receives the request, but in WireMock tests, your applications sends request.

Some working example:

```
// configure static, class-level rule for all tests, like @BeforeClass.
// this launches a Jetty server with configurations
@ClassRule
public static WireMockClassRule classRule = new WireMockClassRule(options().
        port(80).httpsPort(443));

// Divide @ClassRule and @Rule,
// to bypass JUnit limitation of "@Rule cannot be static"
@Rule
public WireMockClassRule rule = classRule;


@Test
public void shouldReturnGivenJson() throws Exception {
    // stubFor() also works; givenThat() is more TDD-ish
    givenThat(post(urlEqualTo("/service2/test")) // <----- note here: without host name
            .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                    .withHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                    .withBody("{\"status\":\"up\"}")));
    // .... your connection here
```

I suggest to begin with `urlEqualTo()`, without messing around with regex. Then you progress to `urlMatching()`.

Also, use `org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils` to get content from the response. This is the official, built-in way to process the response. And, use a `ResponseHandler` because it will `consume()` the response without manually cleaning the resources.

Check HttpClient documentation for more details.